# Laravel image not showing

Tags: php, laravel

Hello everybody i'm new to laravel and php.
today i was able to launch a local laravel website using php artisan serve.

but now i wanted to add a navbar with bootstrap and that worked, but in the navbar i want to add a brand.
unfortunately i have tried many ways to add the path for the image like using ../ and echo path but nothing seems to work. I'm probably doing something wrong :). help is appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>YGP</title>
</head>

<style>
h1
{
    font-family: 'Geneva', sans-serif;
}
</style>

<body>
<nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="" width="50" height="50" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
    YGP
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>

    <div class="content">
        
    </div>
</body>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```

and this is the folder layout:
[the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqVea.png)

located in IMAGES/LOGO.PNG

Comment: your image src is blank here, if your images folder is under public folder then you can put the image src as `asset('images/logo.png')` this will work as `https://project_path/public/images/logo.png`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your **images** folder into **public**. Then access them by

```
<img src="{{ asset('images/logo.png') }}" alt="" title="">
```

Anyways, I recommend you to check with Filesystem. The Laravel Flysystem integration provides simple to use drivers for working with local filesystems and Amazon S3. Even better, it's amazingly simple to switch between these storage options as the API remains the same for each system.

it should help!

For more detail document : https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem

Comment: Sok Chanty, thank you it worked! so this will aslo be the case if i want to use a svg?

Comment: @Yeray you can display it ``<img src="icon.svg" alt="My SVG Icon">``